# How to use substring/charindex to extract a date from a ntext column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, substring, charindex

Example of column I'm pulling from

> SE      IRS                         REC      Ccy:  USD      Face Value:    30,000,000.00      Intr Rte:  -2.386000%      Pmu/Dsc: -63,130.00      INTEREST      ACTUAL/360            Bndswp Int:       2,135.40      1st Pay Date: 01/01/08

Not all rows include the text I'm looking for, which is why I'm wrapping it in a `CASE` expression.

For the rows that do include the target text, it can appear at different points within the field (sometimes at a starting point of 210; sometimes at 198; etc.)

Column comes from the source as `ntext` - no changing that.

**Example of column I'd like to create, titled "1st Pay Date"**

> 2008-01-01

This output needs to be set to data type to operate with other date fields in the same format

Code I've tried

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN [qt_Desc] LIKE '%1st Pay Date%'
        THEN SUBSTRING(
                        CAST([qt_Desc] AS nvarchar)
                       ,CHARINDEX( '1st Pay Date'
                                   ,CAST( [qt_Desc] AS nvarchar )
                                   ,1 ) + 14
                       ,9
                      )
        ELSE 1
    END [1st_Pay_Date],
```

This code currently returns a 0 for "1st Pay Date". I've tried changing the 14 and 9 (start position, search length) and it always returns 0.

When I don't use `CAST`, I encounter this error: *conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value "01/01/08" to data type int*. Using `CAST` solves this error, but I can only `CAST` to nvarchar. Tried using `CAST` within just `SUBSTRING`, within just `CHARINDEX`, and within both.

So I guess a few things I need to accomplish:

- Extract the date following the text: '1st Pay Date'
- Reformat that date to be yyyy-mm-dd
- Set data type to date

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Is 1st Pay Data always at the end of the string with the last 8 characters being the date?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to return two different data types in your case statement and has nothing to do with converting NTEXT to NVARCHAR.

Try this:

```
SELECT
        CASE
             WHEN [qt_Desc] LIKE '%1st Pay Date%'
             THEN SUBSTRING(
                              [qt_DESC]
                             ,CHARINDEX( '1st Pay Date', [qt_Desc] ) + 14
                             ,9
                           )
             ELSE ''
        END AS [1st_Pay_Date],
```

For the other things, I suggest looking into the `CONVERT` function to get a date from a string into the format you want. Note that if you change the value to a date within the `CASE` statement, you will have to change the `ELSE` statement to a date as well. If you wrap the entire `CASE` statement in a `CONVERT`, you will have to change the `ELSE` to a string representing a valid date.